# Probability of guessing two out of five answers in multi-choice test

Tags: probability

I am doing some exercises for a probability class I am taking, but the answer of one confuses me quite a bit. The problem is to calculate the probability of getting two of fewer correct answers on a multi-choice test with three alternatives per question and six questions, if you guess all answers (this might sound similar to [another of my questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438184/succeed-with-one-multi-choice-test-out-of-five-if-answers-are-guessed), but this differs a bit.).

Now, with these circumstances, as only one alternative per question is correct, $P(\text{correct guess}) = {1 \over 3}$. This gives that $P(\text{incorrect guess}) = 1-P(\text{correct guess}) = {2 \over 3}$. So far so good. Then, to calculate the chance to get two or fewer correct answers I chose to calculate
$$\sum_{x=4}^{6}p_\mathbb{X}(x),$$
where $p_\mathbb{X}(x)$ is the probability to get $x$ incorrect guesses. This may not be the shortest path, but I figured it would work. So, I get the following equations:

\begin{gather}
p_\mathbb{X}(x) = {6 \choose x}{({2\over3})^x}{({1 \over 3})^{6-x}} \\
P(\text{two or fewer correct guesses}) = \sum_{x=4}^{6}p_\mathbb{X}(x) \\
\sum_{x=4}^{6}p_\mathbb{X}(x) = {{6 \choose 4}({2\over3})^4({1 \over 3})^{2}+{6 \choose 5}({2\over3})^5({1 \over 3})+({2\over3})^6} \approx 0.68.
\end{gather}

This did, to me, seem fairly reasonable. Then I looked at the answer to the exercise and found this:

$$\sum_{x=0}^{2}p_\mathbb{X}(x) = {6 \choose 0}({1\over3})^6+{6\choose1}({1\over3})^5({2\over3})+{6\choose2}({1\over3})^4({2\over3})^2 \approx 0.100.$$

Now, I can see why their approach would be more straight forward, just adding the probability to get zero, one and two correct guesses. Fine. But it confuses me that the first iteration, ${6\choose0}({1\over3})^6$ calculates the probability of correct guesses in all questions. The answer I found in the book, it seems to me, calculates the probability of getting **two faulty guesses or fewer**. Now, I wonder if I am correct? Does the book indeed provide the probability of getting two or fewer **faulty guesses** rather the two or fewer **correct guesses**, and if it does provide the sought value, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the book is calculating the chance of two or less being faulty.  The second term (once you correct the $\frac 12$ to $\frac 23$) calculates the chance of five guesses correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both for the answer and the correction!